# Any good techniques for Memory Usage optimization for maximum String input length

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I'm designing a string algorithm and the problem lies in the size of the input. By definition Java's maximum string length is 2147483647, to avoid confusion ~2.15x10^9.

Manacher's algorithm requires, by definition an array of characters:

`char[n*2 +3]` where n is the length of the input (string of size n)

By definition the maximum integer is the mentioned above ~2.15x10^9, so an array of characters can be of max size

```
char [ ~2.15x10^9 ];
```

This computation of manachers algorithm in java, lowers the limit of the inputed string to n = (~2.15x10^9 - 3) / 2 . To be accurate thats exactly 1073741822. ~1.1x10^9.

A char array of maximum length has (n*2) + 32 bytes = ( ~2.1x10^9 * 2 ) + 32 bytes = ~4.2x10^9 bytes (4.2GBs)

Theres additional arrays of various sizes, sets and other collections. I believe this will make the program take an entire space of ~~30GBs. for maximal input of RAM memory for the computation of the algorithm which we identified to be at most ~1.1x10^9 characters long.

Could you advice me on some technique to keep things even between "Longest possible string input" and "Memory management" ? Thank you

Comment: Sorry I really confused everybody, now I edited it 2.15 x 10^9 is the correct notation ! Thanks for the comment

Comment: Are you sure your algorithm needs an array of 16-bit UTF-16 characters, and not an array of *bytes*?

Comment: Does this mean the String input has to be converted into bytes to lower the memory usage? Please explain a bit more since I'm still learning computer science

Comment: Do you actually *have* a 4 GB input you want to run this algorithm on? It sounds like you've just taken the absolute limits of Java arrays and assumed your program will operate at those limits.

Comment: Honestly that won't save you more than a factor of 2.  Honestly?  Deal with the limitations; they're not particularly bad.

Comment: You are right @user2357112 , I'm taking the absolute limits and this is wrong. How would you approach a problem like this? What is the recommended cap for such algorithms?

Comment: @s_arabov: I'd approach it by profiling and seeing where my program's heaviest memory usage is actually coming from, if there even is a memory problem. If there is a memory problem, the solution might involve keeping more data on disk, or it might just be to buy more RAM.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is the actual problem you intend to solve using this algorithm? What kind of data do you intend to run it on?

Comment: @GhostCat the algorithm aims to find relations between DNA and RNA strings

Comment: @Andreas I found that hint with x10 9 to be a good preparation for that other "kkk" expression - which I havent seen before; but found very "intuitive".

Comment: Do you need to find the longest palindromic substring? I'm asking because there are other ways apart from the Manacher algorithm to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, but so far I have already designed everything around the Manacher's Algo. What other algorithm's do you have in mind, it wouldn't hurt to check their time comlexity! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/manachers-algorithm-linear-time-longest-palindromic-substring-part-4/), the Manacher algorithm finds the longest palindromic substring in *linear time* (with `n` being the length of the original string).

[Here's an implementation in Java](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/Manacher.java.html), which shows the algorithm is also quite good at memory consumption (you need two arrays, one of chars and another one of ints, both having twice the length of the original string, and you also need to store the original string).

The problem is that your original string is extremely long, so you are reaching language limits, memory limits, etc.

On the other hand, your alphabet consists only of 7 characters: your original string characters `A C T G`, plus a letter separator (such as `#`) and start and end of string characters (such as `$` and `@`). This means that you only need **3 bits** to store each possible character. So, if you are willing to work with *bitwise operators* and *bit masks*, you could store **21 characters in a `long`** (this is because a `long` is represented with 64 bits). This approach would be more complex to code, but it would use much less memory.

Another possible solution would be to work with dynamic structures instead of strings and arrays. These structures would use considerable memory, but it wouldn't be contiguous memory, meaning that you wouldn't reach max array size limits and language limits for ints, etc. This approach uses a [*suffix tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree), which, according to [this article](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/suffix-tree-application-6-longest-palindromic-substring/), is a linear time approach. In that article there's a solution in C++. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the information, your post really helps me a lot! Nucleic acids ACTG and GUAC are ideal for my purpose, I will look into the problem of a C++ suffix tree and working with bitwise operators and bit masks! 

  Thanks a lot once again!

Comment: @s_arabov You're welcome. You know, sometimes, being a developer and being married to a geneticist really helps :)